# Is there a way to Generate a report on a button press

Tags: ms-access

hi I am trying to make a form that will report on a table that is constantly changed and i need it to update a report with new information, is this possible?, ive been looking on the internet for hours with no success.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update"? A report is static, once it's open or printed, it stays as it is. You can of course close and re-open it with the current data.

Comment: i have a rental database which i have been tasked with for some coursework and the criteria is that i generate a report on current rentals that have been issued, but ofcourse information is deleted and addesd to the tables, and im just not sure on how to do this

Comment: What kind of report you are using, just custom coded report or using any reporting tool.
If you are using custom coded report then please use axaj to fetch changes from server at regular interval to update changes

Comment: im just using the ms access report tools, im a compleate begginer

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new report. You can use **Query wizard**.
2. Add a button to the form, and add the following code in the **On click event**

   DoCmd.OpenReport "you report name", acViewPreview

Comment: will the information in the report change with the data in the table or is this done when its done

Comment: All reports are dinamic. A report allways return the actual information.